# CIJoe stuck on "building"

Tags: bash, continuous-integration

I start CIJoe, and it does not move past "Building [branch]...". I know it needs an exit status of 0 for success, so with I put in the Bash script it is supposed to run:

```
exit 0
```

However, it does not change from "Building" to "Built".

The code is [on Github](http://github.com/eturk/fhsclock). The CIJoe config is [here](https://gist.github.com/1205058).

Comment: I noticed the following comment on the CIJoe site: **"Does GitHub use cijoe? No. We use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)."**

Comment: This project is not large enough to need a full-blown CI system. I just need auto-updating and emails when the build works and fails.

Comment: I hadn't heard of CIJoe before, so I went over to take a look. CIJoe looks interesting, but a little on the raw side. Unfortunately, I never used it.

Comment: It's all I really need. It's just this one issue.

Answer (score 0):

just ran into this

if it's stuck (eg: the process doesn't exist anymore)

just go into your repo and `rm .git/builds/current`

and you should be good to restart the build